# .NET SDK for BusinessObjects 3.x

Tags: .net, sdk, crystal-reports, business-objects-sdk

I'm looking at code which uses the CrystalEnterpriseLib library.

I've been wanting to look at the SDK for this. However the archive of SAP is ....., well, all the links are dead:

https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-27446

And they only want to help you if you're a customer.

I'm not even sure which SDK I need. Do you maybe have some of these SDKs lying around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The .NET SDK is very poorly documented, they probably removed it out of shame.  You might have better luck reading the Javadocs, which is better documented and mostly similar to the .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're attempting to accomplish by asking for BOE SDK Help files. Since you referenced the CrystalEnterpriseLib library, I'm assuming you're trying to build something for Crystal Reports.

Here's a link to SAP BOE 3.1 Help Files. I hope this helps.

[BOE Help Files](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ah9hljmpVQ0rkXz2OolT36BUIqWT)